# Amazon SNS doesn't send a notification when a bounce event is fired

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am integrating into our system a functionality when we notify our users when they send an email to a non-existing account (eg. `non_existing_email@my_domain.com`).

In the AWS SNS documentation is said that this event (sending an email on a non-existing email address) is `bounce` (`Permanent`, to be specific).

I have created a topic, subscribed to that topic (confirmed/verified the subscription) and from this point, everything should be ready.

However, when I send out from our system an email to a clearly non-existing email address, the AWS SNS notification is not provided.

What am I missing here?

I thought the problem might be a bad config, so I tried to push a test notification to our system from AWS SNS dashboard, but this notification has been successfully delivered to our endpoint.

Comment: What is the bad email address you tried

Comment: @ArafatNalkhande `email_that_doesnt_exist@my_doman.com`

Answer (score 1):

The issue with 'non_existing_email@my_domain.com' is that AWS SES is not even attempting to send it, saying upfront that it is an invalid domain. So you wont get bounce notification for that.

When you try with 'non_existing_email@mydomain.com' you should get a bounce notification.

So if you want to test that the bounce notification is working or not, ideal way is to use bounce simulator address like 'bounce@simulator.amazonses.com' and if really want to test it with non-simulated address then use some very garbage email address like 'hdxfghfghfgdhdfg@jdfhjdhfjdhfjdhf.jdhfhjhd.

Also keep in mind that we have observed that in certain cases we got bounce notification after 840 minutes (14 hours).

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your message. I played with the a bit and I was able to achieve the following - say my domain is `myweb123.com`. If I send an email to `sfafass@myweb123.com` (non-existing email address), I'll get a bounce notification. That's good. But when I attempt to send an email to `hdxfghfghfgdhdfg@jdfhjdhfjdhfjdhf.jdhfhjhd`, no bounce notification is provided - I just tested it an hour ago, so as you have noticed, I might need to wait longer, so let's see if the notification will get delivered in this case.

Comment: Do not try the exact 'hdxfghfghfgdhdfg@jdfhjdhfjdhfjdhf.jdhfhjhd' target just try similar random string, because it's possible that SES would cache that as a bad email because I had tried that

Comment: An entirely bogus email address at a fictitious domain may not bounce for quite some time, because SES may queue it for retries.  Not a valid test.  Note also that because of the was some mail systems work, a delivery notification event *and* a bounce event can be received for the same message, because some mail systems will accept the message, and then send it back, instead of rejecting it when SES tries to send it.  Such systems are broken, but also fairly prevalent.

Comment: Also, use the bounce simulator: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mailbox-simulator.html#mailbox-simulator-using

Comment: @ArafatNalkhande I've tried multiple non-existing email addresses on non-existing domain names, but never got any bounce back. If I try something like `fn8371gfq8n89f@my_real_domain.com` - from here, I'll get the bounce notification.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I tried the simulator - the email address `bounce@simulator.amazonses.com` and that works fine, I get the bounce notification. I was just surprised that I have never got back the bounce notification for fictional email addresses on fictional domain names (tested about ~10 different e-addresses within the alst 24 hours)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot out of curiosity - when I send an email from my Gmail to some fake account, such as `fmi3@KNASINANVa2ksn.og`, I get back a message by Google daemon that `Address not found`, but when I replicate this action through my system that sends emails through AWS SES (and receive notifications through SNS), I don't get any bounce. Why is that?

Comment: The short, but admittedly unsatisfying, answer is that gmail and SES have chosen to handle those conditions differently.  As long as a mail system is willing to retry sending on your behalf, it is essentially allowed -- but not required -- to keep retrying.